# After an uncommitted bulk insert query, next select query is taking huge time to execute in ORACLE

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have one script in which first a bulk(8 million records) insert is getting executed as shown here
`insert into table2 select * from table1;`

Post insert statement, without commit script is executing below select query which is taking huge time to execute.

`select to_char(SYSTIMESTAMP,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF6') from dual;`

This select query is taking huge time to execute when previous insert is executing for large volume of records(7 to 8 millions). Same query is running fine when insert is happening for 200k records.

Will a commit after insert will help OR what can be the solution to overcome this issue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You must first elaborate what is the cause of the wait. Run the query with 10046 trace, check `V$session´ or *ASH*. You may see also other explanation, *dual* is not a notoric performace killer;)

Comment: if you suspect uncommit query causing slow down on select statement, you might to want to check system performance as a whole, such redo log buffer, or other system process.

Comment: Are you sure the `select ... from dual` is taking a huge amount of time?  Are you sure your timings are correct?  How are you invoking the script? Is the script a PL/SQL block?    If you are using `dbms_output.put_line` calls, the output of those won't appear until the entire block completes.  Try adding the query `select dbms_utility.get_time from dual;` after each of your SQL statements to see where the time really is. (Differences are in 1/100 of a second) And comment by @marmite is the absolute source of truth.

Answer (score 1):

it is related to performance tuning:
after inserting, your table will be fragmented and you should use fragmentation techniques.
In following, some recommendations before and after inserting:

1. Disable all indexes before inserting (Heap table)
2. Enable your indexes after insert
3. Rebuild online your indexes
4. Update the statistics of your schema

after these processes, your fragmentation must be removed.